# Does Firebase-perf plugin supports AGP 8.0 and later?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm trying to use a Firebase performance in AGP 8.1.0 project, but having a problem below:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'.
   > Could not create plugin of type 'FirebasePerfPlugin'.
      > Could not generate a decorated class for type FirebasePerfPlugin.
         > com/android/build/api/transform/Transform
```

Since AGP 8.0, [the Transform API has been removed](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-removed), and I guess the problem is that the Firebase-Perf plugin doesn't support it yet. Does it only happen to me? Or should I report a bug?

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? Can you share your build.gradle(.kts) file so that we can see how you added the plugin?

Comment: Sorry for late. I'm using AGP 8.1.1, firebase BOM 32.3.1 with plugin firebase-perf 1.4.2. 
I'll post an exception log recorded in my idea.log file below:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'FirebasePerfPlugin'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.instantiation.ClassGenerationException: Could not generate a decorated class for type FirebasePerfPlugin.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/transform/Transform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.build.api.transform.Transform

Comment: I migrated my project to Kotlin DSL + version catalog and libraries up-to-date. after clear cache and migration, finally It works. Thanks for support.